# Nodejs, empty body from post data

Tags: node.js

This is my code, very simple:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());

app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(4001, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port ");
});
```

And there are two kind of post need to receive:
One with

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; text/html; charset=utf-8

Another with

> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

I can only receive the second type of post message.
I can receive the first type of post request too, but why the body is empty?
I used wireshake to verified that the body is not empty.

======================================================================
I have tried different method to deal with that post that can get post data successfully.But I don't know why express or body-parse doesn't work for that post.Following is the code:

```
var server = function(req, res){
    var postdata = "";
    req.addListener("data", function(postchunk){
        postdata += postchunk;
    });
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I failed to get the body, am I miss something to setting?

Comment: try removing app.use(bodyParser()); to see if it works

Comment: Still not work for me. The request body still empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a response so that the connection actually completes.  In your app.all, setting something like:

```
res.status(200).send();
```

...works for me.

Comment: Still not work for me. The request body still empty.

Comment: How are you posting the data?  I used curl, and the `res.status` snippet above, and it worked perfectly.  Could there be an issue with your post?

Comment: Thank you for your response.I don't know whether it's an issue with that post.But I have tried another method. If I don't use express and body-parse, I can get all the data of the post.
Following is my code:
    server = function(req, res){
    var postdata = "";
    request.addListener("data", function(postchunk){
    postdata += postchunk;
    console.log(postdata);    
});    
}